# React native styling. width: percentage - number

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I want to do `width: 100% - 50` so I can add an icon which is 50 wide on the right hand side of it.

I have got `width: 100% - 20%` working by using [react-native-extended-styles](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet#installation) but I don't see why that is useful because you can do `width: '80%'`. I cannot get `width: 100% - 50` working. Is there a way?

Trying to use the `onLayout` event to get the container width, then set the `<autocomplete>` to `100% - 50` of the container width but it isn't working.

```
    let Location = (props) => {
      let locationInputElement

      const blur = () => {
        locationInputElement.blur()
      }

      let inputContainerWidth

      return (
        <View style={styles.formItem}>
          <View
            onLayout={(event) => {
              inputContainerWidth = event.nativeEvent.layout.width
              console.log(inputContainerWidth)
            }}

    <Autocomplete
              data={props.autocompleteResults.predictions}...
 style={{
            borderRadius: 8,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            alignSelf: 'stretch',
            paddingLeft: 10,
            position: 'relative',
            ...styles.label,
            ...styles.labelHeight,
            width: inputContainerWidth - 50
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

It does console.log `335` when it console.logs `inputContainerWidth` but the width of the `<autocomplete>` is 100% still.

Comment: Why don't you use flexbox?

Comment: @ViktorSeč Flexbox doesn't have a way to take away 50 pixels from the full width as far as I'm aware of.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'd agree with Viktor, you should be able to achieve this using Flex Box.

Here's something I put together: https://snack.expo.io/B1jDKOhyb

You set the `flexDirection` of the formRow to `row`, and then the first child (the holder `View` for your AutoComplete component to `flex: 1`. This makes it fill all available space. The next child `View` is your icon holder. Which you can set to whatever value you want (in this case 50).

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.formRow}>
          <View style={styles.formItem}>
            // AutoComplete component goes here
          </View>
          <View style={styles.formIcon}>
           // Icon goes here
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 100
  },
  formRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 50,
  },
  formItem: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue',
  },
  formIcon: {
    width: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'greenyellow',
  },
});
```

Comment: That's clean. Looks like what I want, viewing the demo on expo :) Will try it when I get home and mark as answer. Thanks!

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar

Answer (score 21):

This can easily be solved by using Dimensions.

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const MyComponent = () => {
  return <Text style={{height: Dimensions.get('window').height - 100}}></Text>
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: @NavedKhan Awesome, good to hear it worked for you.

Comment: Won't work if you need to subtract from a height other than the window height.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without computing width. Use `marginHorizontal: 50` with `width:100` or `flex:1`.

Your code not working because, it's rendered then `inputContainerWidth` updated. To make it work, there should be another render with new `inputContainerWidth`. So you can't use a stateless component. Change `Location` to regular component and add `inputContainerWidth` to state.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `useWindowDimensions` from `react-native` (see [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions)):

```
import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions();
```

Comment: That's however only for if the dimensions can be based on window.

Answer (score 0):

I did `margin: -50` in the parent and it worked for me